# How to create simple self LVL like library

Tags: android, android-lvl

I have been trying to understand LVL library but without luck. All i need is a simple method that will send and receive current status of License without Policies , just send / reply from  ILicensingService service. I want to create custom LVL library but i must understand it first.

Answer (score 0):

Well, have you taken a look at the actual Market Licensing source files provided by Android? Once you take a few minutes you should be able to understand how the policies work. They are actually simple.

The key class where all the action happens is the `LicenseValidator` class. There is where the licensing check request are taken and there is where the connection to the remote service for licensing checks happens.

In that class take a look how the `Policy` interface class is used.